# Datatables reInitialization (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, initialization, datatables

When I load my page in first place there nothing in the table and the datatable is not initializated, after a few interactions rows are added and when all rows are added (with ajax calls) I init the datatable this way:

```
oTable = $('#table).dataTable( {
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bSortClasses": false,
            "sDom":'T<"clear">',
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "sDom": 'T<"clear"><"fg-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-tl ui-corner-tr ui-helper-clearfix"lfr>t<"fg-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-bl ui-corner-br ui-helper-clearfix"ip>'
        } );
```

The problem is I want to be able to clear that table and keep on adding stuff in the html and then reInit the table from that source code without using fnAddData.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 23):

Calling `$('#table').dataTable().fnDestroy();` will clear the table of `dataTable` code and allow you to manipulate the table, and then call `dataTable` on it again.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use `fnUpdate` and `fnClearTable`? http://datatables.net/api

Comment: I didnt quite understand how fnUpdate worked. fnClearTable, however, I dontw ant to clear it, i want to be able to init it again without getting the alert message.

Answer (score 3):

When you initialize the datatable set bDestroy: true and before adding the update clear table via `$('#myTable').dataTable().fnClearTable();`. Thats it!!

Comment: This did it. fnDestroy() will wipe out pagination buttons. fnClearTable(), if bDestroy is not specified, will not reset pagination buttons correctly.

Answer (score 1):

use the initialization variable `bDestory`. Not **nDestroy**.

Answer (score 0):

to clear the table,  oTable.api().clear().draw();

to reload data from ajax, oTable.api().ajax.reload();

I don't think reInit is a good manner