# How to reset the form and refresh the datatable with a single button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a button with `id="reset"`, So when the button is clicked I want to do two things:

1. The form has to be reset.
2. Refresh the `datatable`.

**Js/jQuery**:

```
$("#reset").click(function(){
    $("myform").reset();
    var oTable = $('#documentreport').dataTable();
    oTable.fnDraw();
}
```

This is what I have tried so far. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I assume you're referring to the [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) plugin?

Comment: Also at end you need to close with }); not }

Comment: if you want to reset the form: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452699/how-to-reset-a-form-using-jquery-with-reset-method), if you want to reset the datatable: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207472/datatables-reinitialization-jquery), took me about 7 seconds

Comment: Finally i got what i wanted.. Here is how i did it                   $( "#reset" ).click(function() {

 $(".target").val("");// target is the class for all the form fields
var oTable=$('#documentreport').dataTable();
oTable.fnDraw();

});    Anyway thanks for ur help guys...

Answer (score 0):

**refresh database:**

Calling `$('#table').dataTable().fnDestroy();` will clear the table of dataTable code and allow you to manipulate the table, and then call `dataTable` on it again.

**Reset form:**
http://jsfiddle.net/8zLLn/

```
  $('#reset').click(function(){
        $('#myform')[0].reset();
  });
```

very well answered by **shmuel613** and **tadiou** thank you both.